# Unable to build Visual Studio 2015 Preview Codova Project in Release Mode - Getting Error - Command failed with exit code 8

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am using Visual 2015 Preview with Cordova Tools, am able to build, deploy application to device or VS Android Emulator without any issues in debug mode. Trouble I am having is when I do it release mode, whenever I am trying to build application in release mode I get below error
**AppPath...\bld\Release\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8** mode

In debug mode it works perfectly fine.

I have all environment variables set as follows as well

1. ADT_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
2. ANT_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3
3. JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
4. Path variable has been appended with **%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;**

All these installation are part of default visual studio installation, except setting up environment variables.

Please let me know what needs to be done to resolve this in release mode.

I have already published my app in app store using VS 2015 preview with Cordova tools, I had to rebuilt my Developer machine/laptop and that's when all this trouble started. I need to publish an update to my app over this weekend but I am stuck now.

Below is Build Output for release mode

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PackagedInterviewApp, Configuration: Release Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(96,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\TFS Application Path....>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat `enter code here`
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\nxqc2vi5.kqy\packages\vs-mda
1>MDAVSCLI : error : C:\TFS Application Path....\bld\Release\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Below is Build Output for Debug mode targeted to device or VS Android Emulator

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PackagedInterviewApp, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(96,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\TFS App Path...>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\nxqc2vi5.kqy\packages\vs-mda
2>------ Deploy started: Project: PackagedInterviewApp, Configuration: Debug Android ------
2>Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe ""C:\Users\....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js"" --platform android --path "C:\TFS App Path...\bld\Debug" --deployTarget "target=169.254.220.177:5555" --language en-US --configuration debug
2>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
2>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
2>  Preparing android project
2>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
2>  Iterating over installed plugins: []
2>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
2>  Wrote out Android application name to "Demo App"
2>  This app does not have launcher icons defined
2>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myapp5fd4c4873c4d44e3a8d208242fbad585"
2>  Running command: C:\TFS App Path...\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild --target=169.254.220.177:5555 --debug
2>  Skipping build...
2>  Built the following apk(s):
2>      C:\TFS App Path...\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
2>  Using apk: C:\TFS App Path...\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
2>  Installing app on device...
2>  Launching application...
2>  LAUNCH SUCCESS
2>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\TFS App Path...\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild,--target=169.254.220.177:5555,--debug
2>  
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Since it works in debug, I guess the problem has to be with signing the package. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

Turn Out to be very Minor Issue, I had migrated to new Dev Environment, I had ant.properties file which had this key == > key.store which points to the file path associated with key store, there was small typo in the path when I had changed it based on the new environment.
VS Studio shows above error, I had to increase the Build verbosity to diagnostic to show me the detail error, once I enabled the build log verbosity to diagnostic I was able to see the detail error.

U can increase verbosity over here
Tools > Options... > Projects and Solutions > Build and run

Answer (score 0):

try this delete this directory

\bld\Release\platforms

Answer (score 0):

For mine, it was the fact that I changed the ID from io.cordova.test to a single name, i.e. bob.  I needed to change it to the format com.company.appname.  As soon as I did that it worked.

I must credit @Amol Gote with his comment on enabling detailed build comments, without which I would not have seen this.